# how to specify maximum search record in google analytics request

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to get data from google analytics and when i am making request, it only returns 1000 records, but i want all the records between this dates.

Can anyone please tell me how to specify maximum record request.

The request is like

```
var  restRequest = gapi.client.request({
               'path': '/analytics/v3/data/ga',
                'method':'GET',
                'params': {
                    'access_token': accessToken,
                    'ids':'ga:69860951',
                    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:entrances,ga:entranceBounceRate',
                    'dimensions':'ga:pageTitle,ga:date',
                    'start-date': d,
                    'end-date' : d1 
                },
                'headers': {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps:

> max-results
>
> max-results=100 Optional. Maximum number of entries to include in this
>   feed. You can use this in combination with start-index to retrieve a
>   subset of elements, or use it alone to restrict the number of returned
>   elements, starting with the first. If you do not use the max-results
>   parameter in your query, your feed returns the default maximum of 1000
>   entries. The Analytics Core Reporting API returns a maximum of 10,000
>   entries per request, no matter how many you ask for.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed#maxResults

Comment: Good job.I just changed the URL link to point to the exact information on the page

Comment: thanks for the reply, but if i have more than 10000 records than ....... can you please tell me  how can i check whether i have more than 10000 records and if i have than how to make another request ?

Comment: see here for handling large data: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed#largeDataResults

Comment: and in the Data Feed you'll find: totalResults—the total number of results for the query, regardless of the number of results in the response